# Unable to compare NSDates due to bad timeZones

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to compare NSDates, mainly just the time, to determine which string should be returned in the forthcoming method, but first here are the calls to set up the dates I am comparing.

```
- (id)init {
    if ( self = [ super init ] ) {
        self.tripTime = 0.0;
        self.timer =
        [ [ BestRouteTimer alloc ] init ];
        self.morningBeforeTrafic = [ self dateWithHour:0 andMinute:0 ];
        self.morningTrafic = [ self dateWithHour:6 andMinute:30 ];
        self.morningAfterTrafic = [ self dateWithHour:9 andMinute:30 ];
        self.afternoon = [ self dateWithHour:12 andMinute:0 ];
        self.eveningTrafic = [ self dateWithHour:15 andMinute:30 ];
        self.eveningAfterTrafic = [ self dateWithHour:18 andMinute:30 ];
        self.timeOfDay = [ self determineTimeofDayWithTime:[NSDate date ] ] ;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The comparing method

```
// Will take the time passed in and return a string
//   to represent the time of day
- (NSString *) determineTimeofDayWithTime:(NSDate *)time {
    NSLog(@"the time of day is \n%@",
          //[ self standardizeDate:time ].description );
    [ time description ] );
    NSLog(@"The before morning trafic is %@",
    //      [ self standardizeDate:self.morningBeforeTrafic ].description );
    [self.morningBeforeTrafic description ]);
    NSLog(@"The morning trafic is %@",
    //      [ self standardizeDate:self.morningTrafic ].description );
    [self.morningTrafic description ]);
    NSLog(@"The after morning trafic is %@",
          //[ self standardizeDate:self.morningAfterTrafic ].description );
    [self.morningAfterTrafic description ]);
    NSLog(@"The afternoon trafic is %@",
          //[ self standardizeDate:self.afternoon ].description );
    [self.afternoon description ]);
    NSLog(@"The evening trafic is %@",
          //[ self standardizeDate:self.afternoon ].description );
    [self.eveningTrafic description ]);
    NSLog(@"The evening after trafic is %@",
          //[ self standardizeDate:self.eveningAfterTrafic ].description );
          [self.eveningAfterTrafic description ]);

    if ( ( [ time compare:self.morningBeforeTrafic ] == NSOrderedAscending ||
          [ self.morningBeforeTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedSame  ) &&
        [ time compare:self.morningTrafic ] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
        return @"Morning, before traffic.";
    }

    else if ( ( [ self.morningTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedAscending ||
               [ self.morningTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedSame  ) &&
             [ time compare:self.morningAfterTrafic ] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
        return @"Morning Traffic!";
    }

    else if ( ( [ self.morningAfterTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedAscending ||
               [ self.morningAfterTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedSame  ) &&
             [ time compare:self.afternoon ] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
        return @"Morning, after traffic ";
    }

    else if ( ( [ time compare:self.afternoon ] == NSOrderedAscending ||
               [ self.afternoon compare:time ] == NSOrderedSame  ) &&
             [ self.eveningTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
        return @"Afternoon";
    }

    else if ( ( [ self.eveningTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedAscending ||
               [ self.eveningTrafic compare:time ] == NSOrderedSame  ) &&
             [ time compare:self.eveningAfterTrafic ] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
        return @"Evening Traffic!";
    }

    else
        return @"Evening, after traffic";

}
```

Finally, here is the method that is generating the dates

```
- (NSDate *)dateWithHour:(int)hour andMinute:(int)minutes {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar ];

    [ calendar setTimeZone:[ NSTimeZone localTimeZone ] ];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *todayComps =
    [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit |NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit) fromDate:today ];
    todayComps.timeZone = [ NSTimeZone localTimeZone ];
    todayComps.minute = minutes;
    todayComps.hour = hour;
    NSDate *newDate = [ calendar dateFromComponents:todayComps ];
    NSLog(@"The time zone is %@", todayComps.timeZone.description );
    NSLog(@"The new date is %@", newDate.description );

    return newDate;
}
```

Here is the log statements

```
2013-11-12 10:29:16.609 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.611 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-12 07:00:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.613 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.615 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-12 13:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.617 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.619 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-12 16:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.622 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.623 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-12 19:00:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.627 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.629 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-12 22:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.632 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The time zone is America/Denver (MST) offset -25200
2013-11-12 10:29:16.633 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The new date is 2013-11-13 01:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.635 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] the time of day is 
2013-11-12 17:29:16 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.637 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The before morning trafic is 2013-11-12 07:00:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.639 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The morning trafic is 2013-11-12 13:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.641 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The after morning trafic is 2013-11-12 16:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.642 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The afternoon trafic is 2013-11-12 19:00:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.644 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The evening trafic is 2013-11-12 22:30:00 +0000
2013-11-12 10:29:16.646 BestRouteFinal[2768:60b] The evening after trafic is 2013-11-13 01:30:00 +0000
```

As you can see the time is off by 7 hours. I am fairly new to ios and this is by far the most complicating thing I have ran into so far. I have searched many posts and tried to implement various solutions but no luck. I have been at this for over a week and don't know what else I can possibly try.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The times are not off by 7 hours. Notice that when you log an `NSDate`, it is logged with a timezone offset of +0000. Midnight in MST is 7am in UTC.

Comment: You got to be kidding me!!! I have tried just about every configuration possible in the documentation and on SO but I never re-logged the value being returned by my comparison method to see if it was working correctly because I was so certain I was doing something wrong due to the logged output. Thanks sir, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` has no concept of a time zone, so regardless of what you do when you go to log it out its going to give you the time based on GMT by default.

As an example, right now for me its 12:44pm EST (or thereabouts by the time you read this). I used your code from above to write the following:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit |NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
comps.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

NSLog(@"New date %@", newDate);
```

That outputs:

```
New date 2013-11-12 17:44:00 +0000
```

Thus it ignores the fact that I set the timezone to my local time zone. However, if I put it within a formatter and log it out you'll notice that the time is now "correct":

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
NSLog(@"Date string %@", [formatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

Outputs:

```
Date string November 12, 2013 at 12:44:00 PM EST
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for future reference. I was only needing to compare the dates so I don't necessarily need to see the date since it is still doing the comparisons correctly. I just made the rookie mistake of not checking that the method was actually performing correctly even though the output I saw seemed wrong. The assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "NSDate has no concept of a time zone, so regardless of what you do when you go to log it out its going to give you the time based on GMT by default." This is incorrect. `NSDate` values are stored in UTC. Logging an `NSDate` calls the `description method. The current implementation of this happens to log the date in UTC. In older versions of iOS, it used to print the date in locale time.

Comment: I would urge you to search around for NSDate's and their concept of a time zone. They do not have one. An NSDate represent the number of seconds since January 1, 2001 GMT. To format it and give it sense of a time zone you would use a formatter.